# conflict with post save and __unicode__(self) in django models

Tags: python, django, unicode, foreign-keys

Apologies for the strange title, but caught on a funny problem involving a conflict with post.save (from a form) and the **unicode**(self) return in my model.

Models.py

```
class NumericTraits(models.Model):
    feature_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    species = models.ForeignKey('Species')
    traits = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cite = models.ForeignKey(Citation)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    dt = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.species_id + self.traits + self.cite_id

class Meta:
    db_table = 'numeric_traits'
    verbose_name = "Numeric Traits"
    verbose_name_plural = "Numeric Traits"

class Citation(models.Model):
    cite_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=25, default=citation_id_create)
    citation_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    citation = models.TextField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.citation_name

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'citation'
    ordering = ['citation_name']
```

views.py

```
def dbPost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save( commit = False)                        
            citeId = request.POST.get("citation", "")            
            post.cite_id = Citation.objects.get(cite_id = citeId)

            post.save()

            return render(request, 'app/SaveSuccess.html') 
        else:
            form = PostForm()
```

In this case, I'm posting a value of (for example) 'citation1' - which refers to the primary key I"m using here.  I use "self.citation_name" (which is "Ainley et al 1995) to display an intuitive name in the django admin.

however, when I go to save, this just gives me an error (e.g., cite_id = Ainley et al 1995 does not exist).

So, it's taking the value of self.citation_name and returning it, then attempting to find the cite_id that matches. However, I want it to return the cite_id value, locate the record, while maintaining the self.citation_name in my model so I can read the admin records easier.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: not sure if this will help but try `return unicode(self.citation_name)`  within the `__unicode__` function.  I remember I had to do this a few times, but I don't remember if it was for this exact sort of scenario.  I believe `__unicode__` requires that the value you return is converted to unicode.

Comment: Thanks - didn't do the trick however.  Getting this error on it.       
    `insert or update on table "numeric_traits" violates foreign key constraint "numeric_traits_cite_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (cite_id)=(Ainley 1995) is not present in table "citation".`

Answer (score 0):

of course... always something simple.. I guess when I was trying to assign "post.cite_id", it was trying to assign it to the foreign key in a funny way.. Fixed this by changing.

```
post.cite_id = .....
```

to

```
post.cite = .....
```